# python: how to read log in web.py server?

Tags: python, web.py

I am using web.py to run a web server. Does anybody know how to read log of web.py server?for example, if another server sends a request to me, this will be recorded in my server log, so how can I see the log in web.py server?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://webpy.org/cookbook/logging) is what you're looking for or at least this is the way...

Comment: Do you know where to download the 'config' module? I have searched but not found.

Comment: I don't think so, this 'config' has no attribute 'log_file', 'log_interval', etc..

Comment: In the link of answer, is is using [wsgilog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgilog/) lib. Those are vars with data that you must set to be used with wsgilog.

Comment: wsgilog runs well in my code, now the only problem is 'config' module, I can't find the correct module which has attribute 'log_file','log_interval','log_backups'